# Automatic unlock item upon save

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, workflow

On Sitecore *v8.2*

If workflow is used, items need to be locked to be edited and explicitly unlocked by the content author when they are done.
To automatically unlock the items upon save, we can change **AutomaticUnlockOnSaved** setting value to *true*. However, that doesn't work on item that doesn't contain any fields eg: Carousel parent folder that would contain carousel items. Carousel parent folder needs to go through the workflow, but since it doesn't have any fields, the item is not unlocked automatically upon item save.

Anyone knows of a way around this?

Comment: Does your carousel parent folder's template inherit from the Standard template? as this should give the item the required workflow fields to allow for the locking/unlocking

Comment: Why lock the item if doesn't have any fields though?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this scenario, by default it doesn't unlock it on save.

However I found something really weird, (I'm using Sitecore 9) if you show 'Standard Fields' from the 'View' tab and then do the same scenario again, it does unlock it on save.

I'm not sure about other Sitecore versions. But if this occurs, this is a bug and should be reported.

Comment: I will file a bug with Sitecore. Thanks @TamerM